# ip6tables - IPv6 DNAT to localhost

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, iptables, ipv6, loopback

I have the following IPv4 rules:

1. `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d "server ipv4" -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -
   j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:55555`
2. `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`

In addition, I have a simple proxy that listens on the `localhost` address: 127.0.0.1:55555

In IPv4 it is working well.

When I tried to do the same in IPv6:

1. `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d "server ipv6 " -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination [::1]:55555`
2. `ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT`

I can't get it to work!

I was able to make it work with:

1. `--to-destination ["link-local IPv6"]:55555`
2. `--to-destination ["Server IPv6"]:55555`

When I turn on forwarding and add some log line in filter-table, forward-chain.

1. `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding`
2. `ip6tables  -I FORWARD  -j LOG --log-prefix='[filter FORWARD] '`

I can see the packet.

> [268332.372177] [filter FORWARD] IN=eth0 OUT=eth0
>   MAC=be:69:fd:2a:9e:bd:0a:08:f1:46:19:a1:86:df SRC=
>   DST=0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=80 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=63
>   FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=42082 DPT=55555 WINDOW=28800 RES=0x00 SYN
>   URGP=0

I can see that the OUT interface is "eth0" and not "lo", and the kernel think that the packet is not intended for this server.

I have centOS 7, and I did try this in Ubuntu 16 as well.

Comment: Try `-j REDIRECT --to 55555` instead of `DNAT`?

Comment: with REDIRECT you cannot redirect to localhost ...

Comment: That is not true, REDIRECT does exactly that. "The REDIRECT target is used to redirect packets and streams to the machine itself." https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x4529.html. Also, it's `--to-ports`.

Comment: I tried with REDIRECT:  ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp   -d <Server ipv6> --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 55555              the result:  [filter INPUT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=be:69:fd:2a:9e:bd:0a:08:f1:46:59:3d:86:dd SRC=<client IPv6> DST=<Server IPv6> LEN=80 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=42092 DPT=55555 WINDOW=28800 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 . the DST is not ::1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a fwmark to what you are doing, and add an ip rule to use a special routing table. In that table you just say: route to dev lo.
The dnat will take care of the rewrite, the fwmark will take care of the route to lo, so your proxy can answer.